# different kind of convergence in Real analysis

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, definition

Now I am studying real analysis, I wonder if anyone can sum up all the relations between all kinds of convergence, convergence in measure, convergence a.e., convergence a.u., and convergence in $L^{p}$, that will be great help for me, if you can give me the detailed how we can get from one kind of convergence to another kind of convergence,, especially between a.u. and $L^{p}$ , I　am always confused with the subsequence about this.

Comment: I'm fond of the diagrams [here](http://www.johndcook.com/modes_of_convergence.html).

Comment: Have you gone through standard references such as Folland's book and whatnot?

Comment: well, I have already have a diagram about this four convergence , but I can not write clearly some proof between them

Comment: This sentence: "I can not write clearly some proof between them," is vey unclear. Each type of convergence has its own definition. What do you mean, "between them?"

Comment: namely how to show from one kind of convergence to get another kind of convergence